# Create a custom Flowable task

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, business-process-management, flowable

I have a requirement where we need to create the custom Flowable Task which have added arguments and hard-coded classes. To do a specific task.
Can anyone help have created such a task?

Also, it is advisable to create the task with hard-coded class in a task.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Flowable Rest API for Create a custom task. using this link http://172.21.111.143:8080/flowable-rest/docs/?url=specfile/process/flowable.json#!/Tasks/queryTasks.

After that you can use create task API for custom task.